# Form data in pycurl request

Tags: python, rest, post, pycurl

I would like to make following curl request with pycurl:

```
curl -v \
-H Accept:application/json \
-F "model={
name: 'zxy',
targets: [ 'abc']
}" \
-F "deployment=@/deployments/MyApp.ear" \
-X POST https://abc.cde
```

How to put to the postfield things that follow *-F* options?

I have currently:

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "https://abc.cde")
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept:application/json'])
c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
# set postfield somehow
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is my conversion of your curl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, pycurl
model = """{
name: 'zxy',
targets: [ 'abc']
}"""
path = '/deployments/MyApp.ear'
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'https://abc.cde')
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept:application/json'])
send = [("model", model),
        ('deployment', (pycurl.FORM_FILE, path)),]
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPOST, send)
#c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
c.perform()
print c.getinfo(pycurl.RESPONSE_CODE)
c.close()
```

It's not easy finding examples of pycurl on forms. None in the [doc](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html), so I downloaded the [source](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl) and used `tests/post_test.py`.